# How to make diffrent registration form for diffrent role

Tags: users

I want to make a registration form that be different for efferent role.
At the first I use the auto assign role for that the user can choose the role.
At now the user can choose him-self's role.
I want if he(or she) choose role "A":
He should answer some field like phone number
and if he(or she!) choose role "B"
He should answer some other field like home address but he cant answer the "phone number" by choosing this role
What should I do?
Is there any module?

Answer (score 1):

[Multiple Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/multiple_registration) module is the answer. I haven't tried it, but here is what it says

> This module adds ability to create role-specific registration pages.
>   Example of situation when this module could help you:
>
> You need to create two user registration pages. One for general users
>   and one, let's say, for hosters. You need to add several specific
>   fields for hoster registration page and these fields should not be
>   available on general user registration page. Furthermore, if you need
>   some hosters fields only on user edit page, without showing these
>   fields on registration page, this module could help you too.

[Profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) is another option. It lets you add different fields for different roles which are not part of user entity as opposed to above module.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Conditional Fields Module](https://drupal.org/project/Conditional_Fields). This module allows you to hide or show fields based on other fields.

Comment: Thank you.But it doesn't work.It wants a field to be depend on it.How can I make a selection field that user can choose him self's role on that?Please say clearly.I have role "A" and role "B". Role "a" should complete the "A" field and role "B" should complete the "B" field.

Comment: Why not? What happens?

Comment: It needs a field to choose the role but I don't have any filed to choose that.The role choosing is provided by auto assign role and it can't match with that module and can't find the fields that created by auto assign module

Comment: OK
you answer is right
but I have now another problem.
I should add a selection box to the registration system that have my role on it.
How can I add selection role box to the registration form that Conditional field module can match with him?
is there any module to add selection role to the registration form?

Comment: I think this is a option of the "Auto Assign Role". From the description: "The second is to allow the end user the option of choosing their own role or roles when they create their account."

Comment: Yes you're right. The Auto assign role has it. But it can't match with the conditional field module.